# How to unpack a vector and send the values as a parameter list?

Tags: scala, future

Consider the following future sequence:

```
val s1 = Future.sequence((1 to 5).map(someFuncReturningFuture))
```

And in the end I want to return a `Future[MyCaseClass]` where `MyCaseClass` is a case class that takes 5 parameters, which I want to be the 5 `Int`s inside `s1`. I thought `s1.map((a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) => MyCaseClass(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5))` should work. How to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I would rather use `mapN` from **cats**.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I found was to do:

```
for (Vector(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) <- Future.sequence((1 to 5).map(someFuncReturningFuture)))
      yield MyCaseClass(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).